# Running Apache not as root for HTTPS

Tags: apache-2.4, docker

I ma trying to make a Docker container image with an Apache server that handles TLS mutual authentication. Since this is a container Apache can be made to listen some high-numbered port instead of 443, so this should remove the need for root execution.

However, as soon as I try to enable TLS, I get this:

```
[Thu Oct 11 09:50:50.357758 2018] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 22] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Oct 11 09:50:50.357818 2018] [auth_digest:error] [pid 22] (13)Permission denied: AH01762: Failed to create shared memory segment on file /run/httpd/authdigest_shm.22
[Thu Oct 11 09:50:50.357825 2018] [auth_digest:error] [pid 22] (13)Permission denied: AH01760: failed to initialize shm - all nonce-count checking, one-time nonces, and MD5-sess algorithm disabled
```

Are root privileges required to create the shared memory or can the access rights be amended to allow non-root usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually figured it out. Listing the access flags on `/run/httpd` shows:

```
drwx--x--- 3 root apache 4096 Sep 24 15:57 /run/httpd/
```

So only root can write there. So in the Dockerfile I added:

```
RUN chmod 770 /run/httpd
```

And it worked. Not sure it the best solution, though, and I welcome any comments that point out problems with that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Applications in containers usually run as root. But that doesn't mean that they have full root privileges.

From the [docker security documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#linux-kernel-capabilities):

> [...] containers can run with a reduced capability set; meaning that “root” within a container has much less privileges than the real “root”.

Just let it run as root inside the container.

Comment: This thing is meant to run in a Kubernetes I don't manage, and the Power That Be mandate that no container shall run as root.

Answer (score 0):

I got another solution for this. In your configuration you can define a directory that you can write, other than /run/httpd/. Like this:

```
DefaultRuntimeDir runtime/
```

This could be a directory relative to your ServerRoot

You can find the document about [httpd core](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#defaultruntimedir) and [mod_slotmem_shm](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_slotmem_shm.html)